# How to show a certain value inside the input tag in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Let's suppose an API call is made at the backend, a value is being fetched from the API, and this value needs to be shown inside the input tag (jsx). How to show that value?

Comment: So you make the call and set a property/state....

Answer (score 2):

You just need to set it your component's state using the `setState` function. A possible scenario might be:

```js
componentDidMount() {
  fetchSomeData().then((data) => {
    this.setState({value: data})
  });
}
/* ... later, in your render function */
<input value={this.state.value} />
```

For more information on how setState works (and to learn more about the entire React lifecycle), see https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate

Answer (score 0):

All you need is to initialize a state. After fetching your api call, update the state and you can use that state in input value:

```
<input value={this.state.value} />
```